# Enable Intel Virtualization Technologies

Tags: android, emulation, virtualization, intel

I want to install Intel HAXM (to make the android emulator faster) but the installer says that my computer "does not support Virtualization Technologies (VT-x)".

In the BIOS I see that that I have Virtualization Technologies enabled, and I have also Windows Phone emulator (that needs this technology) that works very well.

I downloaded the Intel Identification Utility and it says there my Proccessor does not support this technology (although the facts above and search on the internet that shows that my i5 does support this technology).. very strange.

What is the problem and why the utility shows that my computer do not supprots Virtualization Technologies?

I think the problem is with the operating system: Windows 8.1 64bit

[image: Identifcication Utility]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I had the same problem and I solved it by following these steps:

1. Press the <kbd>WINDOWS</kbd> + <kbd>X</kbd>.
2. Choose "**Programs and Resources**" from the list.
3. A window will appear, click on "**Enable or Disable Windows Resources**"
4. From the list that will appear, ***UNCHECK*** the **Hyper-V** folder, click OK.

The hyper-v must be disabled in order to install HAXM.

Maybe you should reboot before trying to install it again.

Comment: Any Solution for Windows 10 OS ,?