# Error trying to install HAXM - Intel VT-x turned off

Tags: android, android-studio, virtualization, haxm

I've Installed Android Studio, and I'am getting this error while I'm trying to install HAXM.

[image]

I tried to enable Virtualization in bios, but It didn't solve the problem. Then I disabled Hyper V in my Windows 8.1 (64 bits):

[image]

After restarting my computer, nothing changed, and I still can't install HAXM for the same reason. How can I solve this issue, assuming that I disabled Avast too, which basically covers all the solution I've found on stackoverflow.

Comment: Hyper-V worked without virtualization in the bios? did you end up leaving the virtualization turned on or off after removing Hyper-V? (or check both cases)? aside from Hyper-V, any other virtualization software? (Virtualbox/etc.?)

Comment: @user2813274 Actually Hyper-V is disabled, and virtualization enabled in bios. No I'm not using any other virtualization software.

Comment: What laptop/desktop might this be, and what processor exactly?

Comment: @matrixanomaly : LENOVO G510 - 4th Generation Intel Core i7-4700MQ Processor (2.4 GHz 1600MHz 6MB)

Comment: @Mfsob gave my answer, after checking out that specific model

Answer (score 3):

You mentioned that your processor was :  Intel Core i7-4700MQ

I've done a quick search for it to determine that Intel HAXM works on your processor. [It does.](http://ark.intel.com/products/75117/Intel-Core-i7-4700MQ-Processor-6M-Cache-up-to-3_40-GHz?q=4700MQ)

You probably fulfill the software requirements for HAXM (Windows 8.1 is Supported, and an up to date Android SDK Manager.

The hardware requirements are:

> Intel® processor with support for Intel® VT-x, Intel® EM64T (Intel® 64), and Execute Disable (XD) Bit functionality
>
> At least 1 GB of available RAM

(Taken from [Installation Instructions](https://software.intel.com/en-us/android/articles/installation-instructions-for-intel-hardware-accelerated-execution-manager-windows))

Given the OS of your system and processor, here's a list of things that you could try in order.

1. **Check the Execute Disable Bit, VT-x, VT-d**

I know this has been mentioned in other answers, but it be good to comb through all the settings again and make sure every virtualization option is properly turned on.

> Within the BIOS setup utility, Execute Disable Bit may be identified by the terms "XD", "Execute Disable", "No Execute", or "Hardware DEP", depending on the BIOS used.

2. **Disable Hyper-V in Windows 8.1**

[This SO question mentions of a fix](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20931978/enable-intel-virtualization-technologies) as other answers here have given, you need to disable Hyper-V due to known conflicts. You did show a screenshot of this being done, the fix does mention of a clean restart (not shutdown and turn on again due to the Fast Startup feature which is a hibernate of drivers).

3. **Alternative: Boot Entry that explicitly disables Hyper-V**

   - Press Start.
   - Type CMD.
   - Right-Click, select Run As Administrator (must do this even if on Admin account)
   - type this in `bcdedit /set hypervisorlaunchtype off`

Instructions adapted from [this blog post](https://forums.ouya.tv/discussion/82/windows-8-how-to-install-intel-haxm-after-installing-hyper-v) that mentions of how to create a separate boot entry. The blog post does touch on turning on Hyper-V after that too.

I personally had issues with HAXM because of the wrong BIOS settings. And perhaps some other virtualization software (I think VirtualBox, it was a while ago) was running. Good luck.

**Edit**: A user also mentioned [here](https://software.intel.com/en-us/forums/topic/328242) that completely uninstalling Avast helped. Not sure if that's the route you want to try.

Answer (score 2):

Run the command to make sure hyperV is off 
        bcdedit /set hypervisorlaunchtype off 
and run this to make sure XD bit is on 
       bcdedit /set nx AlwaysOn 
If you're using Avast, disable "Enable hardware-assisted virtualization" under: Settings > Troubleshooting. Restart the PC and try to run the HAXM installation again
and if nothing is working, try reinstall using the installer from https://software.intel.com/en-us/android/articles/intel-hardware-accelerated-execution-manager

Comment: `The boot configuration data store could not be opened. access is denied` , Getting this trying to execute your command.

Comment: did you run it as admin? (Did you open the command prompt with administrative privileges? You can do this from Task Manager)

Comment: Yes I opened it with administrative privileges.

Comment: sounds like your store is corrupt - you might read thru this
http://pcsupport.about.com/od/fixtheproblem/ht/rebuild-bcd-store-windows.htm

Answer (score 2):

Go to your bios settings and enable  Virtualization  (if ur device support virtualization)

Answer (score 1):

There are 2 parts to virtualization: virtualization of the cpu and IOMMU (memory remapping).  In the Intel world, they are called VT-x and VT-d.  These are usually two different settings in the BIOS.  You may need to enable both for some of the features to work.  Even though the actual text of error says that it needs VT-x, it may need VT-d (as well as VT-x).  I have seen that happen.

Answer (score 0):

Don't change any thing in your system, all you have to go your system BIOS and locate the Virtual Machine setting it must be set to disable change it to enable.

You will most likely find it between those propositions:

- Processor sub menu
- Chip
- North bridge
- Advanced chip set control
- Advanced CPU configuration menu

Check the above menu you should find it.