# Trouble with trying to use Intel HAXM for Android Studio on an HP Envy 15" TouchSmart Laptop

Tags: android, android-studio, virtualization

I know there are questions similar to mine, but since I definitely am a newcomer to Android development, I want to keep my question separate. I'm still also a newcomer to StackOverflow.

I want to learn Android programming as I go through my first co-op term, but there's a problem: **I can't install Intel HAXM on my laptop because I get a popup message saying the same thing as the first dialog shown in this StackOverflow question similar to this one: [Error trying to install HAXM - Intel VT-x turned off](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29333637/error-trying-to-install-haxm-intel-vt-x-turned-off)**

My laptop, however, does support Intel VT-x, and from what I can see on the Intel Processor Identification Utility (it's older than 6 months at the time of this write up), the Intel Virtualization Technology is active (it says "Yes") and so is Intel VT-x with Extended Page Tables. I think I do have HAXM installed already, but I could be wrong.

The laptop is an HP ENVY TouchSmart 15" Notebook PC running on eight Intel Core i7-4700MQ CPUs with the ability to safely reach 2.4 GHz and the ability to be overclocked at 3.1 GHz from the power settings. I'm using the 64-bit version of Windows 8.1.

Without Intel HAXM, I can only run an Android virtual device (so far on API Level 22) using the armeabi-v7a ABI instead of the x86 ABI.

Answer (score 0):

First, you have a fast laptop. haha

By default, Intel Virtualization is off.
turn off laptop, press F10 then press power button. in the tab two or three, you will find the Virtualization setting. just trun on, save and exit bios. restart laptop.

If you are using windows 8. The task manager will tell you current status of Virtualization Technology is on or off.

By the way, you had better have a try of [genymotion](https://www.genymotion.com/). you will love it.