# Unable to download Android studio : Virtualization Technology (VT-x) is not turned on. HAXM cannot be installed until VT-x is enabled

Tags: android, sdk

I got this error during installing. Googled around but didn't get any information.Please advise. Thank you

```
=== Logging started: 5/29/2015  14:25:32 ===
This computer meets the requirements for HAXM, but Intel Virtualization Technology (VT-x) is not turned on. HAXM cannot be installed until VT-x is enabled.
Please refer to the Intel HAXM documentation for more information.
=== Logging stopped: 5/29/2015  14:25:33 ===
```

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20931978/enable-intel-virtualization-technologies

Answer (score 1):

There is so much info missing here. We need to know the operating system you're using and how you're downloading it. But as a quick jump ahead of all that, basically it means that you need to enable Virtualization in your BIOS (if your computer is capable). Google your computer model and Virtualization to see if its possible, or just restart your computer and go into the BIOS menu and check to see if that switch is there.

Comment: Agree. I will keep it in my mind next time when asking questions. I use HP Windows 7 enterprise. I followed your instructions  and that helped me to resolve my issues. I can run my appium tests on mobile devices and my happiness now is priceless. Thanks again

Answer (score 0):

Previously answered

1. Press the <kbd>WINDOWS</kbd> + <kbd>X</kbd>
2. Choose **Programs and Resources** from the list.
3. A window will appear, click on **Enable or Disable Windows Resources**
4. From the list that will appear, Uncheck the **Hyper-V** folder, click Ok.

The hyper-v must be disabled in order to install HAXM.

Download and install  Intel® HAXM

https://software.intel.com/en-us/android/articles/installation-instructions-for-intel-hardware-accelerated-execution-manager-windows

This is the original [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20931978/enable-intel-virtualization-technologies)

Comment: Thank you.. Somehow, Windows+X didn't bring that screen up for me. I use HP windows 7 64 bit Operating system. I followed the instructions above and it worked for me.