# HAXM Virtualisation Install

Tags: android, haxm

I'm a new Android developer and learner, and I am actually facing some strange issue. (config : Intel Core i7 3630QM @ 2.40GHz , 6go ram , windows 8.1)

Just like many, I encountered the HAXM issue when I tried the emulator on the AVD manager.

### What I have done :

**1.  Download the package for intel accelerated HAXM virtualisation  via my SDK manager**

- Figure out the sdk location on my pc, and click on install (manually on the app)

> C:\Users\didier\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\extras\intel\Hardware_Accelerated_Execution_Manager)

**2.1 I get this error**,

> My PC meets the requirements but...

- This means that my HAXM virtulisation may not be enabled on my pc.

**2.2 I checked that on my BIOS, enabled it , saved and exit.**

**3. I retry the install** from the exe file in my sdk location.
   - I get the ***same error message***.

- So I tried install from intel website : [Software from intel Website link](https://software.intel.com/en-us/android/articles/intel-hardware-accelerated-execution-manager-end-user-license-agreement) , ==> I get the ***same 
  error message***

I download **Speccy**, a program that tells you what is on your PC, I found that on BIOS, the Virtualisation option that I enabled , was actually DISABLED.

So I rebooted, and check that, it was ENABLED.

So now, I don't know what to do, I have found some other solution to emulate, but it's quite slow, it uses ARM technology.

Comment: What is your computer's model?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Here is a possible solution to your problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29333637/error-trying-to-install-haxm-intel-vt-x-turned-off/29564801#29564801), what I've found from your information given is that:

Your processor supports HAXM, [see this spec sheet](http://ark.intel.com/products/71459/Intel-Core-i7-3630QM-Processor-6M-Cache-up-to-3_40-GHz).

The hardware requirements are:

> Intel® processor with support for Intel® VT-x, Intel® EM64T (Intel® 64), and Execute Disable (XD) Bit functionality
>
> At least 1 GB of available RAM

Referring to that list of possible solutions, you should try:

1. Double check if **Execute Disable Bit, VT-x, VT-d are turned on** in BIOS
2. Disable Hyper-V in Windows 8.1

   - There have been issues with Hyper-V tech conflicting with HAXM, [refer to this SO question.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20931978/enable-intel-virtualization-technologies)
3. Create a separate boot entry that disables hyper-V completely, or just disable all of it by:

   - Press Start.
   - Type CMD.
   - Right-Click, select Run As Administrator (must do this even if on Admin account)
   - type this in bcdedit /set hypervisorlaunchtype off
   - Reboot. Hyper-V should be off now.

Comment: Hi guys, thanks for answering. I checked on BIOS step 1 : Vitualization option activated.

step 2 : I can't find the Hyper-V folder on my Windows features, I tried to disable it from cmd prompt following : 

'dism.exe /Online /Disable-Feature:Microsoft-Hyper-V-All'

Comment: perhaps you can try step 3 to be sure, what is your computers model?

Comment: I tried step 3 : it said "Operation sucessful" 
But I still get the same error message. 

I checked with a cmd System.info, I saw my HyperVirtualisation enabled.

My PC is laptop HP Envy dv6  windows 8.1


 and it didn't work too... btw I uninstalled Avast, reboot and also shut down my PC.

Comment: You need to reboot to make sure hyper-V goes off, I'll edit my answer

Comment: @dcas don't forget to accept the answer! You also get rep for doing that for your first answer accept. :)

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem with a similar processor, core i3, in my VAIO laptop.  VT was also enabled on the BIOS and the problem was fixed when I uninstalled the avast anti-virus(no disabling the protection) and so I could finish the HAMX installation. After that, I installed the Avast software again.

I hope this issue can help more people.

Answer (score 0):

I had terrible trouble getting an Android Virtual Device to work on Android Studio. I thought I had done everything right but then I checked the Hewlett Packhard BIOS again and realised that the word Enable beside Virtualisation really meant Enable and not Enabled, which is VERY confusing. Switch to Disable (which seems to mean Enabled) and all should be good. Talk about double negatives!